# Simple SFML/C++ question, confused about literal strings and static members

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm a bit confused by the code at http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/graphics-sprite.php

Namely the code at the bottom detailing the class "Missile":

```
class Missile
{
public :

static bool Init(const std::string& ImageFile)
{
    return Image.LoadFromFile(ImageFile);
}

Missile()
{
    Sprite.SetImage(Image); // every sprite uses the same unique image
}

private :

static sf::Image Image; // shared by every instance

sf::Sprite Sprite; // one per instance
};
```

I am trying to use "Init" to load a file to the private image member of the class. I am trying to do this with:

```
if (!Missile::Init("missile.bmp")) return EXIT_FAILURE;\
```

then proceed to declare an object of that class. However, I am getting long, verbose errors that make me think that I should not be putting a string there, or that I am missing something fundamental. I'm a bit new to C++ so the syntax is still confusing me, I've looked at this for quite a while and can't figure it out. I've tried calling pointers, etc, but I really don't know what to do next.

Edit: The error I'm getting is:

main.o: In function Ship::Init(std::basic_string,      std::allocator > const&):
main.cpp:(.text._ZN4Ship4InitERKSs[Ship::Init(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)]+0x10): undefined reference to Ship::Image
main.o: In function Ship::Ship():
main.cpp:(.text._ZN4ShipC2Ev[_ZN4ShipC5Ev]+0x19): undefined reference to Ship::Image

Comment: What is the "long verbose error"?

Comment: I updated my OP with the error.

Comment: And why don't you just derive your missile class from sf::Sprite?

Comment: How do you mean? As in creating a class that's a copy of sprite then adding members for things that I need? Is there a performance benefit to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the term, *long verbose error*, I am just guessing that you might have got confused with linker error. That's because, you might have either forgot to define,

```
static sf::Image Image;
```

in a `.cpp` file or forgot to link that `.cpp` file with your compilation where it's included.
Define your `static` member in appropriate `.cpp` file in *global scope*.

```
sf::Image Missile::Image;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I've tried putting "sf::Image Missile::Image;" before the Init and I get "unqualified use of missile::image" as an error. If "Image" is defined as an "sf::Image" within the class do I have to worry about doing anything else?

Also, I should note that my source code and this class are in the same .cpp file.

Comment: @Gim, **Yes**. For `static` member variables you *also* have to define them in the `.cpp` file (apart from declaring in the class body) and in **global space** (not inside any function). If your `class Missile` is in the same `.cpp` file then you can define this variable just after the class body ends.

Comment: Oh, I must have completely missed that in my reading. Thanks so much, no errors now.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, didn't see that. I just saw the upvote thing but I don't have the reputation to click it. Thanks again, the community here seems so great.

Comment: @Gim As you said you are new to C++; I would suggest that you will learn C++ (or any such language) faster through this community than you try on your own.